# NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'? error closing a pop-up window using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, nameerror

I recently started working with Selenium and I have a problem. The code opens the browser, but after that it gives an error. Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.artfinder.com/#/') #открывает вкладку
sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='close']"))).click()

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Here is the error

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54184/devtools/browser/fc61858b-a717-4088-9d60-46845ee13654
[21956:21112:0404/011021.659:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [01:10:21.658] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\fails\pyt21h.py", line 11, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='next right there_is_link_to_next_episode']"))).click()
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?
```

There is even no suggestion what the error is, no answer was found on the Internet either.

Comment: The error tells you *exactly* what's wrong - `driver` is not defined. You should either rename the instances of `driver` to `browser`, or rename `browser` to `driver`.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?
```

implies the object ***driver*** isn't defined within your program.

---

### Solution

Your webdriver instance is ***browser*** but not **driver**.

So within the *WebDriverWait* instead of `driver` you need to pass *`browser`*.

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='close']"))).click()
```